# removing flex in css for mobile size screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox/flex to center content. However I want to remove the flex properties on screens smaller than 768px

css

```
.row-eq-height {
min-height: 400px;
display: flex;
}

.row-eq-height .col-md-6, 
.row-eq-height .col-md-12 {
flex: 1;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.section-content {
position: relative;
flex: 1;
text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

...
```

I'm not sure what css cancels flex so that I can position my elements differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every class written inside `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}` will override the previous ones.

```
.row-eq-height {
   min-height: 400px;
   display: flex;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    /*display property will be overriden as any class further inside this scope*/
    display: block;
  }
```

As previous answer says `display:initial` or `display:inherit` as any `display` property will cancel `display:flex`.

Comment: what would cancel out flex:1; and align-items:center; or does that need to be overidden?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
flex code here
}
```

Comment: ? I want the flex to work on large screen and not on 768 screens

Comment: with 'min-width' it will work on screens with 768px and above